# Java EE, how to ignore annotations in certain JAR or package

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, weblogic, jax-ws

I'm using a JAR library, which contains `@WebService` annotated classes and other Java EE annotations. The problem is, Weblogic 12c automatically discovers these annotations and provides the services. This is not the intention, rather I would like to use the JAR only as an utility library inside other Java EE project, and ignore all Java EE related configuration from Weblogic point-of-view considering this library.

Basically the library in question is another Java EE project ruthlessly bundled inside a JAR, but modifying the library is out of question, thus I need to ignore all the Java EE stuff in that library.

So, how do I instruct weblogic to ignore all the Java EE related stuff in this specific JAR archive (or alternatively all the classes under certain package specifier) from automatic discovery and configuration?

One solution that comes in my mind is `metadata-complete=true` in `web.xml` which seems to ignore those annotations. However, I'm not sure if it ignores annotations only in JAR libraries or annotations in the project itself too.

Comment: How are you building your application?

Comment: It is the typical EAR with multiple EJB and Web modules. JAR libraries resides in the lib directory.

Comment: What tool are you using to build the jars, web modules, ejb modules and libraries?

Comment: I'm using the ant, and use split development directory structure (I deploy the source folder, and weblogic somehow compiles it)

Comment: You need to modify your ant script so that it uses the library jar as a "source" jar. The script should un-jar it, copy the required classes into a new location and then create a new jar from the new location. I don't believe that there is any other way.

Comment: Do you know why weblogic 11g didn't try to provide these web services, but weblogic 12c does? AFAIK, 11g also support JAX-WS annotations and provides the runtime implementation.

Comment: 11g is a Java EE 5 implementation and 12c is Java EE 7. I believe that the annotation scanning rules became more specifically defined. In particular I think web fragments were added in Java EE 6

Comment: I posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485078/jax-ws-2-0-and-jax-ws-2-2-differences-regarding-annotation-scanning regarding the difference between JAX-WS implenetations in this aspect

Answer (score 1):

You could read about the solution of `metadata-complete` [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/urun_rapp_metadata_lockdd.html). This solution actually was created in order to improve the deployment performance on large scale Java EE projects.

You should try to set `metadata-complete=true` in the web.xml file of the library project and then create a new jar based on this change. This is against your will to refactor the library code, nevertheless it is a minor change which would not take lot of your time.

> However, I'm not sure if it ignores annotations only in JAR libraries or annotations in the project itself too.

You are right. If you make this change in your project's web.xlm file then you will affect your annotations also.

Comment: In the other hand, the library contains web service clients which are actually used (interfaces annotated with `@WebService` and methods with `@WebServiceClient` which produces this port type proxy). Would it also disable the functionality of JAX-WS client without additional XML configuration? The core problem is, there are `@WebService` implementation classes which shouldn't be there, but are unfortunately tightly coupled all around.

Comment: @TuomasToivonen this is not a problem. What this configuration does in to "replace" annotations with deployment descriptors (xml files). The functionality remains the same. So, the functionality that `@WebServiceClient` annotation offers remains. The difference is that this functionality is triggered by the deployment descriptors instead of annotations as I have mentioned above.